# What clause in the C++11 Standard does allow me to eliminate the `A` in the `return` statement in the `A::operator-()` below?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

What clause in the C++11 Standard does allow me to eliminate the `A` in the `return` statement in the `A::operator-()` below? In other words, if I replace the expression `return A{-a.i, -a.j};` by `return {-a.i, -a.j};` the code compiles and executes correctly. I'd like to know how does that work, using the Standard, if possible?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i;
    int j;
    A(int n, int m) : i(n), j(m) {}
};


A operator-(A a) { return A{-a.i, -a.j}; }

int main()
{
    A a(1, 2);
    A b = -a;
    std::cout << b.i << "  " << b.j << '\n';
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't answer how the constructor for A is invoked with the expression `return { -a.i, -a.j };`.

Comment: Yes, that's in [stmt.return]/2, see n.m's answer. (N.B. that's not an expression.)

Comment: Because you says in the function declaration that you are returning an `A` object, so the compiler constructs an `A` object by taking the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in paragraph #3 of section 8.5.4 List-initialization of the C++ Standard

> — Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The
>   applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7). If a narrowing
>   conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments,
>   the program is ill-formed.

End below there is an example

```
struct S {
// no initializer-list constructors
S(int, double, double); // #1
S(); // #2
// ...
};
S s1 = { 1, 2, 3.0 }; // OK: invoke #1
S s2 { 1.0, 2, 3 }; // error: narrowing
S s3 { }; // OK: invoke #2
```

Comment: This answer is the detail of what "copy-list-initialization" means.  n.m.'s answer tells us why "copy-list-initialization" is used in this code.

Comment: @user2337207 This is *not* the correct paragraph. It has nothing to do with return statements. As Ben commented, if you look at n.m's answer, you will see the correct answer.

Comment: @ 0x499602D2 It is the only correct answer that directly answers the question. All other answers do not answer the question "In other words, if I replace the expression return A{-a.i, -a.j}; by return {-a.i, -a.j}; the code compiles and executes correctly. I'd like to know how does that work, using the Standard, if possible?"

Answer (score 10):

6.6.3/2

> A return statement with a *braced-init-list* initializes the object or reference to be returned from the function by copy-list-initialization (8.5.4) from the specified initializer
>   list. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
>     std::pair<std::string,int> f(const char* p, int x) {
>       return {p,x};
>     }
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]